# how to load image on canvas using Promise

Tags: javascript, canvas, es6-promise

i am trying to load images on a canvas from my local folder, this is my js script :

```
function loadElement(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const element = new Image();
    element.addEventListener("load", () => {
      resolve(element);
    });
    element.src = url;
  });
}

//canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

loadElement("./tilesheet.png").then((element) =>
  context.drawImage(element, 0, 0)
);
```

and my html script:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Surface</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

but i get this error: 
**GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/public/tilesheet.png 404 (Not Found)**
and i dont understand why.

Comment: Are you sure the server is not the issue? Have you tried opening the image from that link separately?

Answer (score 2):

Your code loads fine with a known good image:

```js
function loadElement(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const e = new Image();
    e.addEventListener("load", () => { resolve(e); });
    e.src = url;
  });
}

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

loadElement("https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png")
  .then((e) => context.drawImage(e, 0, 0));
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

My guess the error is right, your image is not there: **404 (Not Found)**

Comment: yes thanks,  you are right,  the path Url was not well defined